# Flask application on google app engine - Showing database object

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-app-engine-python

I'm trying to make a flask app on google app engine which shows database entries on their own page.

This is a bit of my views.py code:

```
@app.route('/posts/<int:id>')
def display_post(id):
    post = Post.filter('id =', id)
    return render_template('display_post.html', post=post)
```

Then my display_posts.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<ul>
    <h1 id="">Post</h1>
    <li>
        {{ posts.title }}<br />
        {{ posts.content }}
    </li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Now when I have a post with ID 5700305828184064 and visit this page I should see the title and content:

```
www.url.com/posts/5700305828184064
```

However I get this traceback:

```
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: type object 'Post' has no attribute 'filter'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~smart-cove-95709/1.384741962561717132/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    run_wsgi_app(app)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/util.py", line 99, in run_wsgi_app
    run_bare_wsgi_app(add_wsgi_middleware(application))
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/util.py", line 117, in run_bare_wsgi_app
    result = application(env, _start_response)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~smart-cove-95709/1.384741962561717132/flask/app.py", line 874, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~smart-cove-95709/1.384741962561717132/flask/app.py", line 864, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~smart-cove-95709/1.384741962561717132/flask/app.py", line 861, in wsgi_app
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~smart-cove-95709/1.384741962561717132/flask/app.py", line 696, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~smart-cove-95709/1.384741962561717132/blog/views.py", line 25, in display_post
    post = Post.filter('id =', id)
```

How can I show the title and content of the entry for a given ID?

Comment: You should have `post.title` and not `posts.title` in your template (the same for `content`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a query object first, then apply the filter to that.

```
q = Post.all()
post = q.filter("id =", id)
```

This is the first example in the [GAE docs on queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries).

---

Also, your template references the name `posts`, but you've passed in the name `post`.  Change your template appropriately.